# IF blocks to LOOP

Tags: c#

I really need to shorten my code and turn massive IF operator blocks into LOOP (for, foreach).

When it is in IF blocks - code works.
When it is in FOR loop - code does not work sometimes.

Help would be nice.

IF blocks:

```
            PictureBox tmp = new PictureBox();
        tmp.Bounds = pbxDators.Bounds;

        tmp.SetBounds(tmp.Location.X, tmp.Location.Y, 1, 15);

        if (dt.Bounds.IntersectsWith(tmp.Bounds))
        {
            atskanotAudio(1);
            bumbasStiprums = 3;
            return true;
        }

        tmp.SetBounds(tmp.Location.X, tmp.Location.Y + 10, 1, 15);

        if (dt.Bounds.IntersectsWith(tmp.Bounds))
        {
            atskanotAudio(1);
            bumbasStiprums = 2;
            return true;
        }

        tmp.SetBounds(tmp.Location.X, tmp.Location.Y + 10, 1, 15);

        if (dt.Bounds.IntersectsWith(tmp.Bounds))
        {
            atskanotAudio(1);
            bumbasStiprums = 1;
            return true;
        }

        tmp.SetBounds(tmp.Location.X, tmp.Location.Y + 10, 1, 15);

        if (dt.Bounds.IntersectsWith(tmp.Bounds))
        {
            atskanotAudio(1);
            bumbasStiprums = 0;
            return true;
        }

        tmp.SetBounds(tmp.Location.X, tmp.Location.Y + 10, 1, 15);

        if (dt.Bounds.IntersectsWith(tmp.Bounds))
        {
            atskanotAudio(1);
            bumbasStiprums = -1;
            return true;
        }

        tmp.SetBounds(tmp.Location.X, tmp.Location.Y + 10, 1, 15);

        if (dt.Bounds.IntersectsWith(tmp.Bounds))
        {
            atskanotAudio(1);
            bumbasStiprums = -2;
            return true;
        }

        tmp.SetBounds(tmp.Location.X, tmp.Location.Y + 10, 1, 15);

        if (dt.Bounds.IntersectsWith(tmp.Bounds))
        {
            atskanotAudio(1);
            bumbasStiprums = -3;
            return true;
        }

        return false;
```

And the FOR loop I tried to write to replace that massive IFs:

```
            for (int i = -3; i <= 3; i++)
        {
            PictureBox tmp = new PictureBox();
            tmp.Bounds = pbxDators.Bounds;
            int a = 10;

            if (i == 3)
            {
                tmp.SetBounds(tmp.Location.X, tmp.Location.Y, 1, 15);
                if (dt.Bounds.IntersectsWith(tmp.Bounds))
                {
                    atskanotAudio(2);
                    bumbasStiprums = 2;
                    return true;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                tmp.SetBounds(tmp.Location.X, tmp.Location.Y + a, 1, 15);
                a = a + 10;
                if (dt.Bounds.IntersectsWith(tmp.Bounds))
                {
                    atskanotAudio(2);
                    bumbasStiprums = 2;
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }

        return false;
```

All that code is inside a public function which gets picturebox object as parameter and return bool value..

Why is my FOR loop not working in most cases? If the ball hits middle its sometimes OK but mostly the ball flies through the object bounds. No errors are generated.

Comment: Your variable a is reset to 10 at every loop. Not a chance to change in the loop- Move it before the loop

Comment: You may want to read [this](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/266563/do-non-english-words-increase-the-probability-of-receiving-downvotes/) on meta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be the code you need based on your first code:

```
PictureBox tmp = new PictureBox();
tmp.Bounds = pbxDators.Bounds;

tmp.SetBounds(tmp.Location.X, tmp.Location.Y, 1, 15);

for (var i = 3; i >= -3; i--)
{
    if (dt.Bounds.IntersectsWith(tmp.Bounds))
    {
        atskanotAudio(1);
        bumbasStiprums = i;
        return true;
    }

    tmp.SetBounds(tmp.Location.X, tmp.Location.Y + 10, 1, 15);
}

return false;
```